# Bound for field of definition (vs field of moduli) of an abelian variety

Tags: abelian-varieties, ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $A$ be a principally polarised abelian variety over $\mathbb{C}$ of dimension $g$.
Let $K$ be the field of moduli of $A$.

> **Proposition.** $A$ has a model defined over an extension $L$ of $K$ such that $[L:K]$ is bounded above by a function of $g$.

This follows from the fact that "principally polarised abelian varieties of dimension $g$ with full level-$3$ structure" have a fine moduli space $\mathcal{A}_g(3)$.
Hence the proposition holds with the bound being the degree of the forgetful map $\mathcal{A}_g(3) \to \mathcal{A}_g$.

Is the proposition written down anywhere that I could cite?  I assume it is well-known but I have not been able to find it.  A referee has asked me to provide a reference.

Comment: Why not just include the proof as you have it written in your question?  That will be much more useful to the reader than a reference (which they probably will not lookup, and then just end up confused unless they know already that it's as easy as your proof makes it sound).

Comment: Actually, you don't even need the existence of a fine moduli space (which, after all, is quite hard to prove). The fact that a polarized abelian variety with full level-3 structure has no automorphisms implies that it is defined over its field of moduli, which is of bounded degree over the field of moduli of the polarized abelian variety itself.

Comment: Yes, I shall just include the proof (with anon's simplification).  I was concerned it would distract the reader from the main ideas of the proof in which I use the Proposition but I suppose that it is short enough not to worry about this, especially if I avoid the heavy machinery of a fine moduli space.